# Lucene Tag Searching problems with C#, escape problems?

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

I am using lucene 2.9.2 (.NET doesnt have a lucene 3)

"tag:C#" Gets me the same results as "tag:c". How do i allow 'C#' to be a searchword?  i tried changing Field.Index.ANALYZED to Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED but that gave me no results.

I assuming i need to escape each tag, how might i do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem isn't the query, its the query analyzer you are using which is removing the "#" from both the query and (if you are using the same analyzer for insertion - which you should be) and the field.

You will need to find an analyzer that preserves special characters like that or write a custom one.

**Edit:** Check out [`KeywordAnalyzer`](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_2_0/api/org/apache/lucene/analysis/KeywordAnalyzer.html) - it might just do the trick:

> "Tokenizes" the entire stream as a single token. This is useful for data like zip codes, ids, and some product names.

Comment: I figured it out, i am using WhiteSpaceAnalyzer

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Java Documentation](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_9_2/queryparsersyntax.html) for Lucene 2.9.2 '#' is not a special character, which needs escaping in the Query. Can you check out (i.e. by opening the index with [Luke](http://code.google.com/p/luke/)), how the value 'C#' is actually stored in the index?

Comment: gah, i dont have java installed on this machine. I'm sure one of my VMs does. I'll check it out later. I never knew about luke, +1